# pdfmake does not include fonts / text in node.js

Tags: node.js, pdf, server, pdfmake

I have a problem with pdfmake. I would like to generate a PDF on a node.js server. I would like to load data from a database and draw a nice table and simply save it to a folder.

```
var pdfMakePrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
    ...

      var fonts = {
        Roboto: {
            normal: './fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
            bold: './fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
            italics: './fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
            bolditalics: './fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'
        }
    };
    var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
    var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

    var docDefinition = {
        content: [
            'First paragraph',
            'Another paragraph, this time a little bit longer to make sure, this line will be divided into at least two lines'
        ]
    };

    var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
    pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('pdf/basics.pdf')).on('finish', function () {
        res.send(true);
    });
```

The generated PDF is empty. If I add an image, it is inserted well. But no font is included. The path of the fonts (which are given in the sample) is right.

Has anyone an idea, why no fonts are embedded and how this can be done in node.js? There are no valid samples on the pdfmake documentation.

After some debugging, I found out, that the app crashes in fontWrapper.js in this funktion:

```
FontWrapper.prototype.getFont = function(index){
    if(!this.pdfFonts[index]){

        var pseudoName = this.name + index;

        if(this.postscriptName){
            delete this.pdfkitDoc._fontFamilies[this.postscriptName];
        }

        this.pdfFonts[index] = this.pdfkitDoc.font(this.path, pseudoName)._font; <-- Crash
        if(!this.postscriptName){
            this.postscriptName = this.pdfFonts[index].name;
        }

        }

        return this.pdfFonts[index];
    };
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Argh... The TTF-Files were corrupted. When I use a simple Arial.ttf it works.

Comment: Could you mark your question as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

TTF is not issue in your case you can use any font to generate a PDF on a node.js server.

inside pdfmake

```
TTFFont.open = function(filename, name) {
      var contents;
      contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);
      return new TTFFont(contents, name);
    };
```

on `contents = fs.readFileSync(filename);` this line
`fs` can't read file on given path

as per [This](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/381) conversation you have to put your fonts at root folder,
but problem is when we create font object we gives root path and this path is not working for `fs.readFileSync` this line so you have to exact path of font

add `process.cwd().split('.meteor')[0]` befor font path

I have created example for same functionality please this below link

https://github.com/daupawar/MeteorAsyncPdfmake